# Api Management : can you groupe the operation by controller?

Tags: azure, swagger-2.0, azure-api-management, azure-management-api

my question is about the displaying of the operation list in Azure Api management portal,
i did an import from Swagger 2.0
 in swagger i had the operations grouped by controller:
[image: screenshot from swagger]

and after then import in the portal  : 
[image: Screenshot from api management operation tab]

any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Currently we don't do anything with the tags that are defined in the Swagger/OpenApi definition.  However, the developer portal is customizable, so it might be possible to update the template and change the way the operations are displayed.  You could group them based on the prefix (e.g. Account_ ).

It definitely should be easier than it currently is though.